# How to Install Admin Lists Module In DNN 9

Tags: dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

I was using Admin Lists Module in DNN 8 which got removed in DNN9.

Is there any way to reinstall the module and get it working in DNN9?

Answer (score 1):

I've never head of "Admin List" module. Do you mean "Form and List"? If so you can still download and install it yourself.

https://github.com/DNNCommunity/DNN.FormAndList/releases

Comment: Yes this one.. but for Version 9?

Comment: There isn't any. But most older modules will work with DNN 9 also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the install module from DNN 9.0.1 release . . .

\DNN_Platform_9.0.1.142_Upgrade\Install\Module\DNNCE_Lists_09.00.01_Install.zip